# How to Create product rating programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, review, ratings

I want to create product review and rating programmatically. I was able to create review programmatically by the following code snippet

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1); //desired store id
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$review->setEntityPkValue(1);//product id
$review->setStatusId(1);
$review->setTitle("mytitle");
$review->setDetail("mydetail");
$review->setEntityId(1);                                      
$review->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());      //storeview              
$review->setStatusId(1); //approved
$review->setCustomerId(1);
$review->setNickname("Menickname");
$review->setReviewId($review->getId());
$review->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
$review->save();
$review->aggregate();
?>
```

But I don't know how to create **rating** programmatically. I'm totally blank about it. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through all the voting options and create a rating for each option selected and like it back to your review.

```
foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
     Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
          ->setRatingId($ratingId)
          ->setReviewId($review->getId())
          ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())
          ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
}
```

To get all the ratings you can use the rating's resource collection:

```
    $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->addEntityFilter('product')
        ->setPositionOrder()
        ->addRatingPerStoreName(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load()
        ->addOptionToItems();
```

Then for each rating object you can call `getOptions()` to get each possible option for each rating.

Comment: Can you make it as a code snippet,Because I'm getting exception when using like this.

Comment: I'm getting this -> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'value' cannot be null

Comment: @SIBHIS make sure that the `$optionId` is a valid value for the rating. For example if in the default database rating id 3, which is price has the options 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15 so the option vote value need to be one of these.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  Create product review and rating programmatically

```
function generateReview()
{
    $allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val) {
        $allStoresId[] = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
    }
    $customerId = 120;
    $_ratingValue = 3;

    /* $_customer =  Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId); */
    // IMPORTANT: Set up customer session. The rating/option model resource checks the customer session to get the customer ID.
    /* Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
        ->setCustomer($_customer)
        ->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($_customer);
    */

    if (!$sku){
       return  'Please pass a valid Product SKU';
    } else {
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

        $_review = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->setEntityPkValue($_product->getId())                
            ->setTitle('title')
            ->setDetail('detail')
            ->setEntityId(1) // review_entity: 1 - Product
            ->setStatusId(2) // pending
            ->setStoreId(14) //set default store Id, if multiple stores
            ->setStores($allStoresId)
            ->setCustomerId($customerId) //null is for administrator if store Id is 'O' 
            ->setNickname($nickname)
            ->save();

        // Add review Ratting
        $_ratingOptions = array(
            1 => array(1 => 1,  2 => 2,  3 => 3,  4 => 4,  5 => 5),
            2 => array(1 => 6,  2 => 7,  3 => 8,  4 => 9,  5 => 10),
            3 => array(1 => 11, 2 => 12, 3 => 13, 4 => 14, 5 => 15),
        );

        foreach ($_ratingOptions as $_ratingId => $_optionIds) {
            try {
                Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                    ->setRatingId($_ratingId)
                    ->setReviewId($_review->getId())
                    ->addOptionVote($_optionIds[$_ratingValue], $_product->getId());
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->log($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $_review->aggregate();
    }
}
```

Reference : http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/migrate-products-reviews-and-ratings-programmatically/

Comment: May i know how to import product reviews & ratings bulk import programmatically in Magento 1?   @Pradeep Thakur.